# Classification of all semisimple rings of a certain order

Tags: ring-theory

I'd appreciate it if you tell me where to begin in order to solve this question:

Classify (up to ring isomorphism) all semisimple rings of order 720.

Could the Wedderburn-Artin Structural Theorem be applicable?

Comment: Since you're new, I'd like to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are**. That way, people won't tell you stuff you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Lastly, some may consider your post rude because it is phrased as a command, not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: We clearly need rschwieb here. :)

Comment: I'm surprised that this question got 2 downvotes and 3 close votes.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: I opend a meta question about this. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/whats-wrong-with-this-question

Comment: This is a borderline case, but I think the question shouldn't be closed now. The subsequent edits now provide (a modicum) of their thoughts by asking about applying the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, and they're only asking for a hitn now. This question is easily hintable, after all.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should definitely apply Artin-Wedderburn.

The thing you gain from knowing the ring is finite is that the ring will be a product of matrix rings over fields, since finite division rings are fields. Hopefully you know that all finite fields are of prime power order.

Now then, an n by n matrix ring over a field with q elements clearly has $q^{n^2}$ matrices. Start deducing what the possibilities are :)